# Query XML subchild with Python

Tags: python, xml, api, tableau-api

I'm using Python to query my Tableau server using the API. I'm pulling the revision history of each workbook, and trying to see which user made each edit. Within the revision element, there is a sub-element for the user. I'm trying to understand how to pull the username from this sub-element and associate it with the correct revision data.

Here is an example line of the xml data returned:

```
<tsResponse>
  <revisions>
    <revision revisionNumber="1" publishedAt="2017-01-17 T20:43:40Z" 
     deleted="false" current="true" sizeInBytes="1939262">
    <publisher id="53f212f3" name="1563524" />
    </revision>
  </revisions>
</tsresponse>
```

The element containing id and name is where I'm trying to get the data. I'm able to pull it into a second dictionary list, but I need all the data to be in a single dictionary so I can parse the headers and output to a csv. Here's the relevant bit of code I've written:

```
Pub = []
Rev = []
RevDet = []
revisions = server_response_WB2.findall('.//t:revision', namespaces=xmlns)
publishers = server_response_WB2.findall('.//t:publisher', namespaces=xmlns)
for revision in revisions:
    d = {}
    d['workbook id'] = workbookid[i]
    d['workbook name'] = workbooknames[i]
    d['revision number'] = revision.get('revisionNumber')
    d['revision created at'] = revision.get('publishedAt')
    d['is deleted'] = revision.get('deleted')
    d['is current'] = revision.get('current')
    Rev.append(d)
for publisher in publishers:
    d = {}
    d['user name'] = publisher.get('name')
    Pub.append(d)
RevDet.append(Rev[i])
RevDet.append(Pub[i])
```

As you can see, at the end I'm appending both dictionary lists to RevDet, so the data is closely associated. For example, element 0 and element 1 of RevDet will contain the associated revision and publisher data respectively. Any ideas on how to handle this better? What should my next step be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`revision.find('t:publisher', namespaces=xmlns)` gives you the contained element so then simply use `revision.find('t:publisher', namespaces=xmlns).get('name')` inside the first for statement to extract the value.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the solution I was looking for.